# How to delegate rendering responsibility between ReactJS and ChartistJS for svg

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs, chartist.js

I've created several svg elements using the Charting library [`chartist.js`](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) and now I'm trying to port the svg elements into a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) component. I understand both React and ChartistJS will try to render the svg, and my charts no longer renders due to that issue. I've searched around and found [react-chartist](https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist) but it seems broken with tooltip and touch event issues.

Is there a way where I can integrate my `chartist.js` svg elements into a `React` component while clearly separate and delegate the rendering responsibilities between the two?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this as a starting point -

```
// Chartist data
var data = {
  labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
  series: [
    [9, 6, 4],
    [3, 7, 2]
  ]
};

// React chart component
var ReactChart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.updateChart(this.props.data);
  },
  updateChart: function (data) {
    return new Chartist.Bar('.chart', data);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="chart"></div>
    );
  }
});

// React top level component
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ReactChart data={data} />
    );
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.app'));
```

More detailed examples here - http://www.clintioo.com/2016/01/03/react-charts-with-chartist-js/